# Moving txt files to a folder instead of deleting them in java

Tags: java, file, rename

i have a code to concatenate txt files from a folder and move the concatenated file in another folder.
My code is working well but it deletes files after concatenating them so i would like to move these files to another folder just after concatenating them.

My files from c:\source must be moved to c:\Archive

It was my mistake at the starting, i wanted to move files but i delete them!!
And i would like to throw exception when there is no files in the source folder.

So my code is:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/Target/Filec.txt"));// directory where concatenated file are created

    File file = new File("C:/Source");// where files have to be concatenated and move to c:\Archive before deleting

    File[] files2 = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files2.length; i++)
    {

      File currentFile = files2[i];

      System.out.println("Processing " + currentFile.getPath() + "... ");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currentFile));

      String line = br.readLine();

      while (line != null)
      {
        pw.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
      if (!currentFile.delete())
      {
        // Failed to delete file
        System.out.println("Failed to delete "+ currentFile.getName());
      }
    }
    pw.close();
    System.out.println("All files have been concatenated into Filec.txt");
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To move a file you use `source.renameTo(targetFile)`.

If there are no files in the source dir then `listFiles()` will return an empty array so just check for that and throw.

Also if you just want to blindly concat files you don't need to read line by line, just open a FileInputStream, read chunks into a byte[] and write using a FileOutputStream.  Likely to be much more efficient and simpler.

Comment: +1 for the fact that newlines are not required to concat the file (although it might be nice to put a new line between the files, depending on your specifications, of course.)

Comment: Thank very much for your quick replies friends ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can move a file like so:

```
// File (or directory) to be moved
File file = new File("filename");

// Destination directory
File dir = new File("directoryname");

// Move file to new directory
boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
if (!success) {
    // File was not successfully moved
}
```

Comment: Note that `renameTo` will only work if the source and destination directories are on the same drive.  Moving from one drive to another requires something like `FileUtil.moveFile(...)`; see @Zsolt.

Comment: Interesting - I was unaware of this. Is FileUtil available in the jdk or is the commons jar required?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *File.delete()* use [FileUtils.moveFile()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org)

Comment: +1 - This is the most general solution.  `File.renameTo()` doesn't work if the source and destination are on different drives.